# Dual-monitor setup; one monitor changes to low resolution

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, resolution, monitor

Dear AskUbuntu Community,

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 at work with dual-monitor display. One has 1920x1080 resolution and the other 2560x1440 (main), the graphics card is Radeon 7570 1GB.

The main high resolution monitor (which is connected with DisplayPort) has following issues: sometimes during boot-up or suddenly in the middle of my work (using R or Python, different web tools) the monitor flickers for 2-3 seconds and goes into low-resolution mode. Additionally, it forgets that it's the main one (on the right side) and switches its desktop like it was set up as the left-side monitor.

All I need to do to get it back to work is to click on "Displays" options in the taskbar, not even change anything, just enter the options. It clicks back to its original position and resolution. As you can imagine, it's pretty annoying.

Any ideas on where I could change options ? Or could it be a faulty DisplayPort cable ? I think it started to happen after a colleague of mine pulled out a cable during Ubuntu working to exchange cables. Could some properties get corrupted in the config ?

Best regards,
Piotr

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (in the order presented):

1. Change the power cable that connects the problematic screen to one that you are sure is working. If you continue to have problems,
2. Change the monitor cable (DVI, HDMI, or VGA) with one that you are sure is working. If you continue to have problems,
3. Try another monitor that you are sure is working. If you continue to have problems,
4. Reinstall your display adapter drivers. And if that doesn't work either, then
5. There is something wrong with your hardware (display adapter).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try to follow this general approach, but having in mind that the problem is ALWAYS resolved simply by clicking "Displays" control panel in Ubuntu I would assume that the problem is config-based.